# How to remove an item from Ilist?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have `IList<Detail>` where the `Detail`-Class looks like

```
public class Detail
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Class{get;set;}
  public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want a list where I only have `Name` and `Class` in it. The `Address` should be removed.

How can I do this with linq?

Comment: Which type must be resulting list?

Comment: Do you want to remove the address from the Detail type or set it to null/empty?

Comment: What you need? remove or select ? This is confusing

Comment: I am binding resultant list as a datasource to a repeater so in some cases need to remove Address from List.

Comment: @Tomtom Thanks to understand and editing the question.

Comment: I can not add an answer so I give you the code in this comment. Hope you can read it: var val = (from l in list
                       select new
                           {
                               Name = l.Name,
                               Class = l.Class
                           }).ToList();

Comment: @Tomtom the code provided by you is correct but i have many number items in actual Detail Class so is it possible to remove only that perticuler column from Detail class?

Comment: @Mohit: Why do you need to remove the `Address` from the datasource? You just have to use an appropriate `ItemTemplate` with controls that bind to `Name` and `Class`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually i am working on existing code and can't modify code in this way.Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
List<Detail> newDetailList = existingDetailList.Select(x => new Detail
                               {
                                   id = x.id,
                                   name = x.name
                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. can we do that with existing List?

Comment: @Mohit, you can loop and set `null`